# I can't use numpy astype to convert string to float

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to use np.array to convert list to array, and then convert data to float. But the data type is U15, i don't know what it is. I can convert several row data to float by array2[0:2].astype(np.float),but can't convert the entire array to float. What is done in the for loop is the screening of qualified data.

The data is more than 1 million, and a part of data is:

```
33,Jogging,49105962326000,-0.6946377,12.680544,0.50395286;
33,Jogging,49106062271000,5.012288,11.264028,0.95342433;
33,Jogging,49106112167000,4.903325,10.882658,-0.08172209;
33,Jogging,49106222305000,-0.61291564,18.496431,3.0237172;
33,Jogging,49106332290000,-1.1849703,12.108489,7.205164;
33,Jogging,49106442306000,1.3756552,-2.4925237,-6.510526;
```

The code is as below:

```
import numpy as np
file = open("WISDM_ar_v1.1_raw.txt", "r")
list_arr = file.readlines()

length = len(list_arr)
list1 = []
#print(length)
for i in range(length):
    list_arr[i] = list_arr[i].rstrip("\n")
    list_arr[i] = list_arr[i].rstrip(";")
    list_arr[i] = list_arr[i].split(",")
    if len(list_arr[i]) == 6:
        list1.append(list_arr[i])
    else:
        pass

array1 = np.array(list1,dtype=str)
print(array1.dtype)
array2 = np.delete(array1, [0,1], axis=1)
print(array2[0:2])
print(array2.dtype)
array2 = array2.astype(np.float)
print(array2)
```

The error is:

```
<U15
[['49105962326000' '-0.6946377' '12.680544' '0.50395286']
 ['49106062271000' '5.012288' '11.264028' '0.95342433']]
<U15
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Anaconda/network/.idea/testfloat.py", line 22, in <module>
    array2 = array2.astype(np.float)
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

Comment: You should print out `array2`. It probably contains a string like `"Jogging"`, which obviously can't be converted to a float.

Comment: `array1` has `dtype `str`, which in Py3 is unicode.  Evidently some strings in that `list1` are long enough to require 15 characters. hence `U15`.  But when you tell it to convert that array to float, one or more of those strings cannot be converted,   Maybe the `Jogging`?

Comment: How would you expect "Jogging" to become a float? You should probably use Pandas rather than numpy. Also note you should look into the CSV module, you're currently reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I was going to suggest that too, but I don't think it supports custom line termination (`';\n'`). I guess you could just trim that off that last one though?

Comment: `U15` is a 15-"character" (code points) long unicode string.

Comment: @BaileyParker `lineterminator` is part of the [dialect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#dialects-and-formatting-parameters), or you could just trim it from the last item as part of the other processing.

Comment: I have deleted the first and the second column by array2 = np.delete(array1, [0,1], axis=1)  so jogging is not non-existent

Comment: Try pandas: `df = pd.read_csv(filename, lineterminator=';', header=None)`. `df.iloc[:, 2:].values` will give you a float numpy array.

Comment: @ayhan Thank you very much.By trying pandas, i get the correct result , but my dataset is so large and the time it needs is so long, Is this normal?

Comment: @hpaulj Thank you very much for your reply. I have deleted the Jogging column, so i don't know why it can't convert

Comment: @Evert Thank you very much for your reply.

Comment: @Thank you very much for your reply.I used pandas and numpy to deal with data, i found that pandas need more time than numpy. I don't know if it's normal. I will read what you suggest. Thank you.

Comment: @BaileyParker Thank you very much for your reply. I edited the code and print two row of array2.  Custom line termination (';\n') is correct .And what should i do to trim that off that last one ?

Comment: I was just looking at this fordham dataset :D @ohdoughnut do you know what is that 3rd column ?

Comment: Found it: 3rd column is phone's uptime in nanoseconds.

Comment: @JemshitIskenderov yes, it is time stamp

Comment: @ohdoughnut readme says sampling frequency is 20hz(1 sample in every 50ms) but when i check the difference bwn line it is 110ms mostly. Do you know why?